# @TImed with extraTags and @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, annotations, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a method with annotation like this:

```
@Timed(value="timed", extraTags={"account", Account.getById(@PathVariable("id")}
public Info getInfo(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return Info.getById(id);
}
```

The above does not work of course. Hopefully, you can see what I'm trying to do.  What is the correct syntax to set the account tag to the value returned by Account.getById() given an id on the path?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you'll be able to use the `@Timed` annotation to accomplish what you're doing, but you can manually time the method and do what you want.  Here is an example:

```
.
.
.
@Autowired MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
.
.
.
public Info getInfo(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    final Sample sample = Timer.start(meterRegistry);

    final Info info = Info.getById(id);

    sample.stop(Timer.builder("timed")
                     .tag("account", Account.getById(id)
                     .register(meterRegistry));
    return info;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is **NOT** possible to pass values the way that you're expecting to `@Timed` or any other annotation for that matter. Values passed to any annotation must be a compile time constant.

A compile time constant is something like:

```
private static final String tag = "account";
```

The value returned by `Account.getById()` is not a compile time constant and hence cannot be accepted by an annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to do it using annotation called [@MeterTag](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/3727)

So for example you can do it like this:

```
@Timed
public Info getInfo(@MeterTag("id") @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return Info.getById(id);
}
```